# Polymer breaks with old version of Mootools

Tags: polymer, mootools, web-component

**Latest Update (also updated post title)**

So I tracked down the issue to the old version of Mootools (which I cannot upgrade or remove due to project restrictions).
Mootools does the following, which is the code that causes the issue:

```
/*
Class: Abstract
    Abstract class, to be used as singleton. Will add .extend to any object

Arguments:
    an object

Returns:
    the object with an .extend property, equivalent to <$extend>.
*/

var Abstract = function(obj){
    obj = obj || {};
    obj.extend = $extend;
    return obj;
};

//window, document

var Window = new Abstract(window);
var Document = new Abstract(document);
```

The new definitions of Window and Document is what's breaking Polymer imports. Any suggestions on updating the code above to gracefully extend the Document/Window objects without breaking existing functionality?

**OLD description below before I discovered the issue lies with mootools**

I've already included the webcomponents.js script.
Then, when I have the  for polymer.html, the errors below start appearing, and my polymer components doesn't work.

The components works in isolation using the polymer-cli. Anyone know what may be causing this issue?

[image: Chrome devtools screenshot]

**EDIT**: So this is what I have in my `<head>`

```
<script src="/media/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="/media/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
```

(...sorry I cannot show more, private company code and what-not)

That's literally all I need in my page to raise the error mentioned above.
I'm starting to think there is some other javascript library (there's a lot) that might be interfering with Polymer, since I cannot replicate the issue on a brand new site.

I should also note, there are no 404's. The polymer.html file does get loaded as expected in the browser, I verified this in my network panel in developer console.

Comment: We are probably going to need some code to be able to help you :)

Comment: I didn't add any code because there is literally almost none of my own elements yet. I get this error the moment I import polymer.html

Comment: Well, we need some context. Where are you including those files? It would be helpful to be able to recreate your error :)

Comment: how are the serving it? caddy, python or apache?

Comment: Could definitely use some code here. How are you importing Polymer. and where.

Comment: I've edited the post. As you can see it's literally just that bit in <head> that I require for the error to be raised. Hence why I'm so perplexed, since I've not run into this issue before, and I've used Polymer for over 2 years now

Comment: Is it possible for you to recreate the scenario using some dummy code, as you cannot post original code here?

Comment: ... am starting to suspect that Mootools is the culprit here. I'll dig around a bit more.

Comment: It's definitely Mootools version that we are using. I've selectively enabled/disabled many other scripts on the site and this error ONLY happens when I enable mootools... I'll try some workarounds and will report back.

Comment: When you write _"The new definitions of Window and Document is what's breaking Polymer imports."_ I'm not sure that is the problem since `Window != window`. Maybe some missconfiguration in the imports? some upper/lower case being mixed?

Comment: @Sergio thee reason I believe it's them, is because I had console.log(Document.prototype.importNode) before and after those var declarations. The log output before the definitions, displayed the expected output in the console, where log output after, raised the error mentioned in my post.

Comment: I'm struggling with this right now - trying to get a Polymer component working on a Joomla site (it's otherwise fine), so I can't just eliminate mootools. Any headway on addressing the mootools incompatibility?